# How to obtain specific row or column in a numpy array where their first element meets the requirement?

Tags: python, numpy

Let´s assume we have a matrix in form of numpy array. The matrix contains data (outer products of physical quantity when two independent variables are at certain values) obtained from some experiment.

```
matrix = np.asarray([(None,200,210,220),
                     (260,1.2352,6.436,4.863),
                     (270,23.2346,21.436,0.4643),
                     (280,6.1345,7.45,10.236)])
```

200,210,220 and 260,270,280 are values of those two sets of independent variables.
I wanted to get the data when the variable equals 220 or 270 only. So the following is expected:

```
[4.863, 0.4643, 10.236]
[23.2346,21.436,0.4643]
```

How can I achieve that without hard-coding, since `matrix[1:,3]` or `matrix[2,1:]` won´t bring any convenience if the condition is changed.

I am confused about the boolean indication of numpy array and can´t go further after this:

```
>>matrix[0,:] == 220
>>matrix[:,0] == 270

array([False, False,  True, False])
array([False, False, False,  True])
```

update: This problem is solved, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def column(matrix, value):
    index = np.where(matrix[0, :] == value)[0].item()
    return matrix[:, index]
print(column(matrix, 220)[1:])

def row(matrix, value):
    index = np.where(matrix[:, 0] == value)[0].item()
    return matrix[index, :]
print(row(matrix, 270)[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build your matrix using pandas DataFrame, so that you can have rows and columns indexed and you can filter them out more easily:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame({"200":[1.2352,23.2346,6.1345],
                       "210":[6.436,21.436,7.45],
                       "220":[4.863,0.4643,10.236]},
                       index=[260,270,280])


print(matrix.loc[:,"200"])
print(matrix.loc[270,:])
```

Output:

```
260     1.2352
270    23.2346
280     6.1345

200    23.2346
210    21.4360
220     0.4643
```

For the boolean indication you are indicating the condition, what you need to do now is to filter your matrix based on your condition.

```
matrix[matrix[0,:] == 220]
matrix[matrix[:,0] == 270]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I chose numpy because the data are needed for further matrix manipulation (substraction with other matrices obtained from implementing outer product).

Comment: ```matrix[matrix[:,0] == 270]``` would work. But ```matrix[matrix[0,:] == 220]``` will produce ```[[280 6.1345 7.45 10.236]]```, which is not what is expected.